# Inserting data into table automatically based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, triggers

Reading about `Triggers`, `Equi-Joins` and `cross-joins` has my head spinning and unable to figure out what i need.

Basically, I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1: Users
    id
    username
    score

Table 2: Acts
    act_id
    act
    user_id
    act_score

Table 3: Votes
    vote_id
    act_id
    user_voter
    score_given
```

When a vote is cast, I want mysql to automatically add the `score_given` to the users `score' and to the`act_score`.

Is this possible and what type of `JOIN` and/or `TRIGGER` would I need. And if someone is feeling really generous, could they provide me with the sql code? I am really struggling to get my head around this...

Comment: you need `after update` TRIGGER on Votes table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `VIEW` to calculate scores for each `User` or `Act` as needed. That would guarantee that scores will always be correct and you would not need a lot of triggers.

**UPDATED:**

1) Remove scores from `Users` and `Acts` tables;

2) Create a view `ActsWithScore`:

```
CREATE VIEW ActsWithScore AS 
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT SUM(Votes.score) FROM Votes WHERE Votes.act_id = Acts.act_id) AS act_score
FROM Acts;
```

3) Create a view `UsersWithScore`:

```
 CREATE VIEW UsersWithScore AS 
    SELECT 
        *, 
        (SELECT SUM(ActsWithScore.act_score) FROM ActsWithScore WHERE ActsWithScore.user_id = Users.id) AS user_score
    FROM Users;
```

4) Now you can query data by following commands:

```
SELECT *
FROM UsersWithScore
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM ActsWithScore
```

After you have done all these changes, don't forget to change `Users` to `UsersWithScore` and `Acts` to `ActsWithScore` in all the places where you are querying the score.

PS. Sorry, I don't have MYSQL at hand right now, so bear with me if there are some syntax errors.

Comment: How would I use `VIEW`?

Comment: Thank you, will try now. I don't have to change anything in my script as I haven't implemented the vote/score system yet. Am starting to build it as we speak :)

Comment: Updated with sample using `VIEW`s. I really recommend to switch to this solution as `TRIGGER`s usually are considered to be a bad practice as they can do unexpected things while updating data.

Comment: Sorry for the late vote but I had a few bugs to deal with before I could try this out. Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A trigger is the most obvious solution but it can add a maintenance issue. If you app is not that big/complex you ill be fine.
Also I prefer to do both inserts at business layer. If you are doing a insert, why not do two inserts? It can add overhead to your application but if your app is not a doing that thousands times/sec you ill be fine.

Comment: You can easily go in 'out-of-sync' state as you can easily forget to change information all across the database.

Comment: A good business layer implementation cannot allow that. A trigger is like a event firing the execution of a SP. That trigger can fail messing with your data (very likely to happen if don't put relational integrity and transactions to good use). btw I like your view suggestion depending on scenario is what I can use.

Comment: I mostly agree with you that good implementation of business layer would not allow data to go 'out-of-sync' and you should be fine, but you can't be sure that everything will always go through this layer. As in every real life application time-to-time you might run in to need to correct some data manually inside the database - either because of bug or user error. In cases like this is better if there is no data duplication and you don't need to update data in different places. But as you already said it fully depends on what type of application we are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME 

AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
// Insert into another table values ( new.x, new.y...);
END;
```

Comment: I'm guessing I just type this into the sql part of `mysqladmin` and it will be set up automatically?

Comment: if you have heidiSql or editor, you can right clik on table n do